# How to put a Google Cloud Run service behind Cloud CDN?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-cdn

I want to put a CDN in front of a Google Cloud Run service in order to cache some responses.

Right now it seems Cloud CDN requires a Google Load Balancer, and they cannot point to a Google Cloud Run service (https://github.com/ahmetb/cloud-run-faq/tree/e7a0fc43d3054456613c09e073db289ddf76dd33#how-can-i-configure-cdn-for-cloud-run-services).

Is there another way?

Comment: I thought I could do it via a Internet Network Endpoint Group pointing to the `[...].run.app` domain, but it's a dead-end.

Comment: This *is* coming in the medium term - both HTTPS Balancing & Cloud CDN will be able to front Cloud Run. See https://twitter.com/ahmetb/status/1227653149835448320 for an example! If you have an account team, please reach out to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[updated]

You can use Cloud CDN with Cloud Run via [Google Cloud Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/serverless-neg-concepts)

Comment: Available through load balancing since 2020-07-07: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/release-notes#July_07_2020 .

As reflected in https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/using-gcp-services#connect-trigger

Answer (score 1):

Additionally it's possible without using the Load Balancer by serving it through a Firebase app by adding a `Cache-Control` [header](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-cache#set_cache-control) and via a [rewrite rule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run#direct_requests_to_container) in `firebase.json` (via the unofficial [Cloud Run FAQ](https://github.com/ahmetb/cloud-run-faq#how-can-i-configure-cdn-for-cloud-run-services)).